# What does the "Hotel Paparazzi" use in Recep İvedik 1 (2008)?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-identification, camera-identification

[There is a scene involving the hotel paparazzi trying to take a picture of the main character.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxggzHIV-wE)

What I find funny is how I have my own mid/late 2000s Nikon like the dude has. I have a D80/18-135 but my camera is bit less boxy so I wonder how close I got to the camera and the guy uses. He also seems to have some "backup" camera something like that.

What I also wonder is, would that make a logical vacation photo setup for some resort hotel (Eg Nashira Resort Hotel in the movie)back in the day and now? The photos later get used in some billboard. In 2022 the digital age of Instagram and ignorant people using "Image" as opposed to document in WhatsApp to butcher the megapixels off their 50MP photos a commonplace thing nowadays but I think who knows I even heard, even few Megapixels is enough-ish for small prints.

[image: Billboard]

Comment: Better shot of the camera - still too small to read - https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUlCu.jpg The picture embedded above doesn't seem to be from the YouTube clip posted.

Comment: @Tetsujin it's actually from a later scene that is about the "male genitelia" hand gesture getting shown by kid and other photogpapher getting flamed for it. I thought maybe they used the same camera as a prop